# $E$ measurable iff for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a measurable $U\supset E$ s.t. $m(U\backslash E)<\varepsilon$.

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove that $E$ measurable if and only if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a measurable $U\supset E$ s.t. $m(U\backslash E)<\varepsilon$.

For the implication it's obvious since there is if $E$ measurable, there is an open $O\supset E$ s.t. $m(O\backslash E)<\varepsilon$, and since $O$ is measurable, we have the result. For the reciprocal I tried many things, but impossible to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

Take an open $O\supset U$ s.t. $m(O\backslash U)<\varepsilon.$
Then $$O\backslash E=(O\backslash U)\cup (U\backslash E).$$
Use the sub additivity of $m^*$ to conclude.

Comment: I see, thank you. Can you look at this question ?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519071/show-that-there-is-no-continuous-function-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-such-that-f

Comment: Please don't ask for an answer to a question in other questions.